# A multitude of challenging logarithmic integrals (First part)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

The following challenging integrals are coming from the new preprint ["The derivation of eighteen special challenging logarithmic integrals" by Cornel Ioan Valean](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/334598773_The_derivation_of_eighteen_special_challenging_logarithmic_integrals) where they are nicely evaluated.

> The following equalities hold:
>   $$i) \ \int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-x) \log ^2(x) \log(1+x^2)}{x} \textrm{d}x$$
>   $$=\frac{1461}{256}\zeta (5)+\frac{7 }{128}\pi ^2 \zeta (3)+\frac{\pi ^5}{96}-\frac{\pi ^3}{8}G-\frac{\pi}{768}\psi ^{(3)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right);$$
>   $$ii) \int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+x) \log ^2(x) \log(1+x^2)}{x} \textrm{d}x$$
>   $$=\frac{\pi}{768}\psi ^{(3)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)+\frac{\pi ^3}{8}G-\frac{\pi ^5}{96}-\frac{5}{128}\pi ^2 \zeta (3)-\frac{1515}{256}\zeta (5);$$
>   $$iii) \ \int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-x) \log ^4(x) \log(1+x^2)}{x} \textrm{d}x$$
>   $$=\frac{121557}{1024}\zeta (7)+\frac{105}{512}\pi ^2 \zeta (5)+\frac{121}{2560}\pi ^4 \zeta(3)+\frac{9}{320}\pi^7-\frac{5}{32}\pi^5G-\frac{\pi^3}{512}\psi ^{(3)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-\frac{\pi}{20480}\psi ^{(5)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right);$$
>   $$iv) \ \int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+x) \log ^4(x) \log(1+x^2)}{x} \textrm{d}x$$
>   $$=\frac{\pi^3}{512}\psi ^{(3)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)+\frac{\pi}{20480}\psi ^{(5)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)+\frac{5}{32}\pi^5G-\frac{9}{320}\pi^7-\frac{75}{512}\pi ^2 \zeta (5)-\frac{119}{2560}\pi ^4 \zeta(3)-\frac{122283}{1024}\zeta (7);$$
>   $$v) \ \int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-x) \log ^6(x) \log(1+x^2)}{x} \textrm{d}x$$
>   $$=\frac{41184405}{8192} \zeta (9)+\frac{6615 }{4096}\pi ^2 \zeta (7)+\frac{1815}{4096} \pi ^4 \zeta (5)+\frac{2017}{14336} \pi ^6 \zeta (3)+\frac{479 }{3584}\pi ^9-\frac{61}{128} \pi ^7 G$$
>   $$
> -\frac{25 }{4096} \pi ^5\psi ^{(3)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-\frac{3 }{16384} \pi ^3\psi ^{(5)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-\frac{\pi }{458752}\psi ^{(7)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right);
> $$
>   $$
> vi) \ \int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+x) \log ^6(x) \log(1+x^2)}{x} \textrm{d}x
> $$
>   $$
> =\frac{\pi }{458752}\psi ^{(7)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)+\frac{3 }{16384} \pi ^3\psi ^{(5)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)+\frac{25 }{4096} \pi ^5\psi ^{(3)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)+\frac{61}{128} \pi ^7 G-\frac{479 }{3584}\pi ^9$$$$
> -\frac{2015}{14336} \pi ^6 \zeta (3)-\frac{1785}{4096} \pi ^4 \zeta (5)-\frac{4725 }{4096}\pi ^2 \zeta (7)-\frac{41229675}{8192} \zeta (9),
> $$
>   where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function, $\displaystyle \psi^{(n)}$ denotes the Polygamma function and $G$ represents the Catalan's constant.

**Question**: For example, it's not hard to see that 
 \begin{equation*}
\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-x) \log ^2(x) \log(1+x^2)}{x} \textrm{d}x
\end{equation*}
  \begin{equation*}
 =\frac{7}{48} \pi ^2 \zeta (3)-\frac{1}{4} \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^{n-1}\frac{ H_{2 n}}{n^4}-\frac{1}{2} \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{n-1} \frac{ H_{2 n}^{(2)}}{n^3}-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^{n-1}\frac{ H_{2 n}^{(3)}}{n^2}.
\end{equation*}

How would you calculate individually each of the resulting harmonic series and then get the values of the given integrals? Are these series known in the mathematical literature?

A note that might be useful: one might establish a relation between $i)-ii)$, $iii)-iv)$ and $v)-vi)$ by adding them and observing that the resulting integrals are of the type,

> \begin{equation*}
> \int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-x)\log^{2n}(x)\log(1+x)}{x} \textrm{d}x
> \end{equation*}
>   \begin{equation*}
> =\frac{1}{2}(2n)!\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}\right)\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \zeta(k+1)\zeta(2n-k+2)-(2n)!\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{2k-1}}\right)\zeta(2k)\zeta(2n-2k+3)
> \end{equation*}
>   \begin{equation*}
>  +\frac{1}{2^{2n+3}} (2n+3-2^{2n+3})(2n)!\zeta(2n+3),
> \end{equation*}
>   which is a generalization that is established in the book **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**, see page 6.