# A multitude of challenging logarithmic integrals (Third part)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

In this post you'll find the last group of logarithmic integrals from the new preprint ["The derivation of eighteen special challenging logarithmic integrals" by Cornel Ioan Valean](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/334598773_The_derivation_of_eighteen_special_challenging_logarithmic_integrals) which are evaluated beautifully by fruitfully combining the Fourier series and the integral representation of the Polylogarithm given in Section 1.6, page 4, from the book **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series** (it is also stated in the preprint - see Lemma 4), to turn the single integrals into double integrals.

> The following equalities hold:
>   \begin{equation*}
> i) \ \int_0^1 \frac{\log ^2(x)}{x}\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{2 x}{1+x^2}\right) \textrm{d}x=\frac{3}{64}\log (2)\pi ^4 +\frac{5}{48}\pi ^2 \zeta (3)-\frac{31}{128} \zeta (5);
> \end{equation*}
>   \begin{equation*}
> ii) \ \int_0^1 \frac{\log ^2(x)}{x}\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-\frac{2 x}{1+x^2}\right) \textrm{d}x=-\frac{7}{192}\log (2)\pi ^4-\frac{1}{12}\pi ^2\zeta (3)-\frac{31}{128} \zeta (5);
> \end{equation*}
>   \begin{equation*}
> iii) \ \int_0^1 \frac{\log^4(x)}{x}\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{2 x}{1+x^2}\right) \textrm{d}x=\frac{33}{640} \log (2)\pi ^6+\frac{89}{960} \pi ^4 \zeta (3)+\frac{13}{32} \pi ^2 \zeta (5)-\frac{381}{512} \zeta (7);
> \end{equation*}
>   \begin{equation*}
> iv) \ \int_0^1 \frac{\log^4(x)}{x}\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-\frac{2 x}{1+x^2}\right) \textrm{d}x=-\frac{31}{640}\log (2) \pi ^6-\frac{91}{960}\pi ^4 \zeta (3)-\frac{19}{64} \pi ^2 \zeta (5)-\frac{381}{512} \zeta (7);
> \end{equation*}
>   \begin{equation*}
> v) \ \int_0^1 \frac{\log^6(x)}{x}\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{2 x}{1+x^2}\right) \textrm{d}x
> \end{equation*}
>   \begin{equation*}
> =\frac{2193}{14336}\log(2)\pi ^8+\frac{215}{768}\pi ^6 \zeta (3)+\frac{113}{128} \pi ^4 \zeta (5)+\frac{825}{256}\pi ^2 \zeta (7)-\frac{22995}{4096} \zeta (9);
> \end{equation*}
>   \begin{equation*}
> vi) \ \int_0^1 \frac{\log^6(x)}{x}\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-\frac{2 x}{1+x^2}\right) \textrm{d}x
> \end{equation*}
>   \begin{equation*}
> =-\frac{2159}{14336}\log (2)\pi ^8-\frac{217}{768}\pi ^6 \zeta (3)-\frac{7}{8}\pi ^4 \zeta (5)-\frac{1185}{512}\pi ^2 \zeta (7)-\frac{22995}{4096}\zeta(9).
> \end{equation*}

**Question:** Is it possible to avoid completely the use of Fourier series and calculate it by another route involving harmonic series and generating functions with harmonic series?

A note: Starting from these forms and getting integrals from the previous two posts, [A multitude of challenging logarithmic integrals (First part)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3299644/a-multitude-of-challenging-logarithmic-integrals-first-part) and [A multitude of challenging logarithmic integrals (Second part)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3299669/a-multitude-of-challenging-logarithmic-integrals-second-part) might be an easier task. However, starting from the previous two groups of integrals and reducing the calculations to the integrals from this post **is not something obvious** at all. Good to know where we start from!

This is assured by the identity:

> **A special dilogarithmic identity**. Let $x<1$ be a real number. Then the following equality holds:
>   \begin{equation*}
> \int_0^x \frac{t \log (1-t)}{1+t^2} \textrm{d}t=\frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{1}{2} \log^2(1+x^2)-2 \operatorname{Li}_2(x)+\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-x^2\right)+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{2 x}{1+x^2}\right)\right),
> \end{equation*}
>   where $\displaystyle \operatorname{Li}_2(x)=-\int_0^x\frac{\log(1-t)}{t}\textrm{d}t$ is the Dilogarithm function.